# How to select all href attribute in a html tag contain a common class. in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-shell

I want to select all the href contains in  tag ...
here is my html code

```
<a href="/gp/product/0545935172 ...." class="aok-block aok-nowrap" title="Dog Man: Lord of the Fleas: From the Creator of Captain Underpants (Dog Man #5)">
```

I used `response.css('a.aok-block::attr(href)').extract()`

but the result is: [ ]

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use xpath expressions. For your example `response.xpath("//a[class='aok-block aok-nowrap']").get_attribute('href')`

Answer (score 0):

Add to the answer johnnydoe

Will be:

```
    response.xpath('*//a/@href').extract_first()
    response.xpath('*//a/@class').extract_first()
    response.xpath('*//a/@title').extract_first()
```

If you want get only href then you must find upper tag...like this:

```
    <li>
    <a id="nav-questions" href="/questions">
    </li>
```

Will be:

```
    response.xpath('...some uniq selector.../li/a/@href').extract_first()
```